# Filter on Smart-Table data source

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'd like to filter my data source as its passed to Smart-Table but I can't see a way to do it. I can filter in the ng-repeat, but the pagaination doesn't respect this. Something like this...

```
<table st-table="dataView0" st-safe-src="data | filter: { Stage: 0 }" class="table1 table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in dataView0">
```

Is it possible? If so how please?

Comment: The pagination will only "respect" your filtering it those are done using `st-search`, I found it better to use your own paginator and add filters to ng-repeat, ui-bootstrap pagination is a great alternative